# I have to draw the corresponding transistor-level schematic of the CMOS layout below

Tags: transistors, inverter, cmos, layout

I am an electrical engineering student and I have the following assignment:
'Draw the schematic that is correspondent to this whole layout'.
I can understand how to translate the inverters from the A,B,C and D,E parts but I cannot seem to find any solution to the connections of the pins from C to D. Until now I have the solution below, which I know it is not fully correct. Can someone help me with an explanation on it?
[image: CMOS layout]

[image: Transistor level circuit]

Comment: How can you "translate an inverter" while being unable to reverse engineer the other structures? My guess is that you learned what an inverter looks like in the layout but not what an NMOS or PMOS looks like in a layout. In the inverter layout, can you point out what the Drain, Source and Gate are? If so then do the same on the other part of the layout. Just "blindly" draw NMOS and PMOS symbols on top of the layout. Note that getting Source and Drain mixed up does not matter as these are physically identical anyway.

Comment: You are still missing a PMOS and an NMOS transistor, maybe start there?